# Difference between frompyfunc and vectorize in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

What is the difference between [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) and [frompyfunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc) in numpy?

Both seem very similar. What is a typical use case for each of them?

**Edit**: As JoshAdel indicates, the class `vectorize` seems to be built upon `frompyfunc`. (see [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6dcc6e45ac8c5e4fd0beb047364b8341a5c6b3c1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1877)). It is still unclear to me whether `frompyfunc` may have any use case that is not covered by `vectorize`...

Comment: Any numpy developers out there who can clear this up?  Numpy has many of these situations where there were higher and lower level implementations without a pointer between them in the docs.

Comment: For some secret reason, `frompyfunc` produces functions that consciously disregard the `dtype` argument and return an array of `object`s.  As the documentation explains, "The returned ufunc always returns PyObject arrays". There is an easy and ingenious workaround: submit an array of desired type as `out` argument.  The `vectorize` function, on the contrary, allows to specify the output type of the ufunc with `otypes` argument, but it is supposed to be slow and hence fairly useless, compared to using nested lists.

Comment: If anyone wants to take the speed arguments further, there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253839/why-vectorize-is-outperformed-by-frompyfunc/74596788#74596788) Q/A, that offers 1000x speedup.

Answer (score 28):

As JoshAdel points out, `vectorize` wraps `frompyfunc`.  Vectorize adds extra features:

- Copies the docstring from the original function
- Allows you to exclude an argument from broadcasting rules.
- Returns an array of the correct dtype instead of dtype=object

**Edit:** After some brief benchmarking, I find that `vectorize` is significantly slower (~50%) than `frompyfunc` for large arrays.  If performance is critical in your application, benchmark your use-case first.

`

```
>>> a = numpy.indices((3,3)).sum(0)

>>> print a, a.dtype
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]] int32

>>> def f(x,y):
    """Returns 2 times x plus y"""
    return 2*x+y

>>> f_vectorize = numpy.vectorize(f)

>>> f_frompyfunc = numpy.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1)
>>> f_vectorize.__doc__
'Returns 2 times x plus y'

>>> f_frompyfunc.__doc__
'f (vectorized)(x1, x2[, out])\n\ndynamic ufunc based on a python function'

>>> f_vectorize(a,2)
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  6,  8],
       [ 6,  8, 10]])

>>> f_frompyfunc(a,2)
array([[2, 4, 6],
       [4, 6, 8],
       [6, 8, 10]], dtype=object)
```

`

Comment: Intersting... but the differences and use cases are still pretty much unclear to me...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what the different use cases for each is, but if you look at the source code (/numpy/lib/function_base.py), you'll see that `vectorize` wraps `frompyfunc`. My reading of the code is mostly that `vectorize` is doing proper handling of the input arguments. There might be particular instances where you would prefer one vs the other, but it would seem that `frompyfunc` is just a lower level instance of `vectorize`.

Comment: I agree with you that `frompyfunc` seems to be lower level than `vectorize`. The question remains, though, of whether there are cases where you would prefer to use `frompyfunc` instead of `vectorize`?

Comment: I think you cannot use `.accumulate` in `vectorize` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912352/3226167

Answer (score 6):

Although both methods provide you a way to build your own *ufunc*, *numpy.frompyfunc* method always returns a python object, while you could specify a return type when using *numpy.vectorize* method