# how to speed up loop in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to speed up this code  :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv(path)
closep = a['Clsprc']
delta = np.array(closep.diff())
upgain = np.where(delta >= 0, delta, 0)
downloss = np.where(delta <= 0, -delta, 0)
up = sum(upgain[0:14]) / 14
down = sum(downloss[0:14]) / 14
u = []
d = []
for x in np.nditer(upgain[14:]):
    u1 = 13 * up + x
    u.append(u1)
    up = u1
for y in np.nditer(downloss[14:]):
    d1 = 13 * down + y
    d.append(d1)
    down = d1
```

The data below:

```
0     49.00
1     48.76
2     48.52
3     48.28
...
36785758    13.88
36785759    14.65
36785760    13.19

Name: Clsprc, Length: 36785759, dtype: float64
```

The for loop is too slow, what can I do to speed up this code? Can I vectorize the entire operation?

Comment: what is the size of `a['Clsprc']`?

Comment: Programmatically I would look for a way to parallelize the operation such as a parallelized implementation of NumPy array or another collection data type (such as is available with Scala collections).  There are a number of ways to parallelize for loops, for example see https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html.  Anaconda has an MKL optimizations package specifically for improving performance of NumPy, SciPy, scikit-learn, and NumExpr, see https://store.continuum.io/cshop/mkl-optimizations/, however its not free.

Comment: Is that really the right code?  Those multiplications by 13 look very strange to me-- your values will inf out in no time.  I *think* you're trying to compute a rolling mean and you forgot the divisions, but since your code isn't documented, you don't explain what you're trying to do, and your implementation seems weird, it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to calculate an exponential moving average (rolling mean), but forgot the division. If that's the case then you may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/moving-average-function-on-numpy-scipy) SO question. Meanwhile, here's a fast a simple moving average using the `cumsum()` function taken from the referenced link.

```
def moving_average(a, n=14) :
    ret = np.cumsum(a, dtype=float)
    ret[n:] = ret[n:] - ret[:-n]
    return ret[n - 1:] / n
```

If this is not the case, and you really want the function described, you can increase the iteration speed by getting using the `external_loop` flag in your iteration. From the numpy documentation:

> The nditer will try to provide chunks that are as large as possible to
>   the inner loop. By forcing ‘C’ and ‘F’ order, we get different
>   external loop sizes. This mode is enabled by specifying an iterator
>   flag.
>
> Observe that with the default of keeping native memory order, the
>   iterator is able to provide a single one-dimensional chunk, whereas
>   when forcing Fortran order, it has to provide three chunks of two
>   elements each.

```
for x in np.nditer(upgain[14:],  flags=['external_loop'], order='F'):
    # x now has x[0],x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5] elements.
```

Comment: For a 1d array, the external loop iter just hands out the whole array in one step.  It is the same as `x=upgain[...]`.

Comment: How is "as large as possible" determined?  Can this be used to process a mmap array by breaking it into chunks that fit in memory?

Answer (score 0):

In simplified terms, I think this is what the loops are doing:

```
upgain=np.array([.1,.2,.3,.4])    
u=[]
up=1
for x in upgain:                  
    u1=10*up+x
    u.append(u1)
    up=u1
```

producing:

```
[10.1, 101.2, 1012.3, 10123.4]
```

`np.cumprod([10,10,10,10])` is there, plus a modified `cumsum` for the `[.1,.2,.3,.4]` terms.  But I can't off hand think of a way of combining these with compiled `numpy` functions.  We could write a custom `ufunc`, and use its `accumulate`.  Or we could write it in `cython` (or other `c` interface).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912352 suggests that `frompyfunc` is a way of writing a generalized `accumulate`.  I don't expect big time savings, maybe 2x.

---

To use `frompyfunc`, define:

```
def foo(x,y):return 10*x+y
```

The loop application (above) would be

```
def loopfoo(upgain,u,u1):
    for x in upgain:
        u1=foo(u1,x)
        u.append(u1)
    return u
```

The 'vectorized' version would be:

```
vfoo=np.frompyfunc(foo,2,1) # 2 in arg, 1 out
vfoo.accumulate(upgain,dtype=object).astype(float)
```

The `dtype=object` requirement was noted in the prior SO, and  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4155

```
In [1195]: loopfoo([1,.1,.2,.3,.4],[],0)
Out[1195]: [1, 10.1, 101.2, 1012.3, 10123.4]

In [1196]: vfoo.accumulate([1,.1,.2,.3,.4],dtype=object)
Out[1196]: array([1.0, 10.1, 101.2, 1012.3, 10123.4], dtype=object)
```

For this small list, `loopfoo` is faster (3µs v 21µs)

For a 100 element array, e.g. `biggain=np.linspace(.1,1,100)`, the `vfoo.accumulate` is faster:

```
In [1199]: timeit loopfoo(biggain,[],0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 281 µs per loop

In [1200]: timeit vfoo.accumulate(biggain,dtype=object)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.4 µs per loop
```

For an even larger `biggain=np.linspace(.001,.01,1000)` (smaller number to avoid overflow), the 5x speed ratio remains.