# Faster loop operating on two values of an array

Tags: python, loops, numpy, optimization, numpy-ufunc

Consider the following function:

```
def dostuff(n, f):
    array = numpy.arange(0, n)
    for i in range(1, n):                    # Line 1                      
        array[i] = f(array[i-1], array[i])   # Line 2
    return numpy.sum(array)
```

How can I rewrite the Line 1/Line 2 to make the loop faster in python 3 (without using cython)?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)? Docs say it's primarily about convenience, but it might gain a little in some cases.

Comment: How would you do that with Python vectorize?

Comment: is your function `f` completely a custom function ? or it might be implemented by `numpy` somewhere ? can you share it's implementation

Comment: f can be anything taking two integers and returning an integer

Comment: Looks to me like the use-case is too simple to really take advantage of `numpy`'s strengths.  I've not timed, but maybe something like `sum(f(x, x+1) for x in range(n-1))` will actually be faster?

Comment: @zehnpaard actually your code is not producing the desired result , as the function needs to accumulate results

Comment: @NaderHisham Ah yes you're quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to check this question on `SO` [generalized cumulative functions in NumPy/SciPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828599/generalized-cumulative-functions-in-numpy-scipy) , since you want a `generalized cumulative function` .

also check scipy documentation for the function `frompyfunc` [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html)

```
func = np.frompyfunc(f , 2 , 1)

def dostuff(n,f):
    final_array = func.accumulate(np.arange(0,n), dtype=np.object).astype(np.int)
    return np.sum(final_array)
```

### Example

---

```
In [86]:
def f(num1 , num2):
    return num1 + num2

In [87]:
func = np.frompyfunc(f , 2 , 1)

In [88]:
def dostuff(n,f):
    final_array = func.accumulate(np.arange(0,n), dtype=np.object).astype(np.int)
    return np.sum(final_array)

In [108]:
dostuff(15,f)
Out[108]:
560

In [109]:
dostuff(10,f)
Out[109]:
165
```

### Benchmarks

---

```
def dostuff1(n, f):
    array = np.arange(0, n)
    for i in range(1, n):                    # Line 1                      
        array[i] = f(array[i-1], array[i])   # Line 2
    return np.sum(array)

def dostuff2(n,f):
    final_array = func.accumulate(np.arange(0,n), dtype=np.object).astype(np.int)
    return np.sum(final_array)

In [126]:
%timeit dostuff1(100,f)
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.6 µs per loop

In [127]:
%timeit dostuff2(100,f)
The slowest run took 4.98 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Except that the non-vectorized version returns [0, 1, 3, 6] I guess

Comment: I got the issue , it's somehow tricky :) , I've updated my answer