# Optimize the following section of python code for decaying variables

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, data-science

I'm doing the following operation on a sorted dataset '`df_pre_decay`' containing time-series dataset for multiple IDs and I want to decay my '`tactic`' variables for each ID at different rates (coming from `tactic_decay_dict`).

The created variable for decayed tactic variable '`xyz`' will have same value as the tactic variable in 1st mnth while for all the other mnth , it will be an addition of ((value of decayed tactic variable '`xyz`' in the previous mnth) multiplied by rate) and ((value of tactic variable 'tactic' in the current mnth) multiplied by (1-rate))

```
time_col = 'mnth'
tactic =['overall_details','speaker_total','overall_samples_eu','copay_redemption_count','voucher_redemption_count','dtc']
tactic_decay_dict = dict.fromkeys(tactic,(60,70))

uniq = len(df_pre_decay[time_col].unique())

## Loops for variables and decay rate
for a in tactic_decay_dict:
    for b in tactic_decay_dict[a]:
        xyz = a+'_s'+str(b)
## Loops for iterating over each row in the dataset
        for i in range(len(df_pre_decay)):
            df_pre_decay[xyz] = np.where((i%uniq)!=0,
                                         (df_pre_decay[xyz].iloc[i-1])*b/100+
                                         (df_pre_decay[a].iloc[i])*(100-b)/100,
                                         df_pre_decay[a].iloc[i])
```

I want to optimize this section of code as it is taking more than 30 mins for 5 million+ rows in my dataset.

Edit: Please find the sample of dataset

```
ID  mnth    overall_details speaker_total   overall_samples_eu  copay_redemption_count  voucher_redemption_count    dtc
1   201701  3   1   10  9   3   6
1   201702  6   1   0   7   7   10
1   201703  10  8   7   8   9   10
1   201704  3   9   3   0   1   1
1   201705  9   0   8   9   6   4
1   201706  8   3   2   10  8   9
1   201707  3   10  3   0   5   6
1   201708  2   10  3   9   6   2
1   201709  1   3   7   10  8   0
1   201710  3   8   2   8   0   10
1   201711  6   7   4   8   5   6
1   201712  3   8   2   9   4   10
2   201701  7   4   7   4   10  2
2   201702  10  0   2   2   10  5
2   201703  10  6   4   10  5   3
2   201704  4   3   6   4   0   8
2   201705  7   8   9   10  6   10
2   201706  8   0   2   7   1   8
2   201707  10  2   8   1   9   4
2   201708  10  6   7   0   3   5
2   201709  10  10  3   8   9   0
2   201710  2   0   3   5   5   8
2   201711  1   8   0   7   3   4
2   201712  8   5   1   0   7   9
3   201701  2   2   7   7   1   2
3   201702  2   8   10  9   6   9
3   201703  10  5   8   5   9   4
3   201704  6   1   2   4   6   2
3   201705  6   9   4   4   3   0
3   201706  5   1   6   4   1   7
3   201707  0   7   6   9   5   6
3   201708  10  3   2   0   4   5
3   201709  5   8   6   4   10  4
3   201710  8   3   10  6   7   0
3   201711  7   5   6   3   1   10
3   201712  3   9   8   4   10  0
```

Comment: Can you please post some kind of sample dataframe? (some small sample, just for an algorithm to work). It will be very helpful

Comment: Could you please share a sample input dataframe and output dataframe.

Comment: I've added the sample of dataset as you asked

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code will work as intended, because you effectively set the entire column `df_pre_decay[xyz]` to a single value in each round of the loop. You need *either* to loop through each row of the dataframe (`for i in range(len(df_pre_decay))`), or treat the columns as vectors (as `np.where` and other numpy functions do), but you are mixing up both. A vectorized approach will usually be much faster.

For a non-vectorized version, set column `xyz` to be the same as column `a` and then loop through the rows, setting the accumulating values where needed.

```
for a in tactic_decay_dict:
    for b in tactic_decay_dict[a]:
        xyz = a+'_s'+str(b)
## Loops for iterating over each row in the dataset
        df_pre_decay[xyz] = df_pre_decay[a]
        for i in range(len(df_pre_decay)):
            if i % uniq != 0:
                df_pre_decay[xyz].iloc[i] = (df_pre_decay[xyz].iloc[i-1] * b/100
                     + df_pre_decay[a].iloc[i] * (100 - b)/100)
```

Or an alternative version - not sure which will be faster:

```
for a in tactic_decay_dict:
    for b in tactic_decay_dict[a]:
        xyz = a+'_s'+str(b)
        column = []
        for i, x in enumerate(df_pre_decay[a]):
            if i % uniq == 0:
                current = x
            else:
                current = x * b/100 + current * (100-b)/100
            column.append(current)
        df[xyz] = column
```

To vectorize, you can break the columns into chunks and applies the cumulative decay function to each, using [`numpy.ufunc.accumulate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828599/generalized-cumulative-functions-in-numpy-scipy).

```
for a in tactic_decay_dict:
    for b in tactic_decay_dict[a]:
        xyz = a+'_s'+str(b)
        decay_func = np.frompyfunc(lambda u, v: u * b / 100.0 + v * (100-b) / 100.0, 2, 1)
        decayed = np.array([])
        for top in range(0, len(df_pre_decay), uniq):
            chunk = df_pre_decay[a][top:top+uniq]
            decayed = np.concatenate((decayed, 
                                  decay_func.accumulate(chunk, dtype=np.object).astype(np.float)))
        df_pre_decay[xyz] = decayed
```

An alternative way would be to insert blank rows with null values in between the different IDs. You could then apply a single accumulating function to the whole columns:

```
# insert blank rows in the data
df.index = df.index + df.index // uniq
df.reindex(index=range(len(df) + len(df) // uniq))   

def get_decay_func(b):
    def inner(u, v):
        if pd.isnull(u) or pd.isnull(v):
            return v
        else:
            return u * b/100.0 + v * (100-b)/100.0
    return inner

for a in tactic_decay_dict:
   for b in tactic_decay_dict[a]:
        decay = get_decay_func(b).accumulate
        xyz = a+'_s'+str(b)
        df_pre_decay[xyz] = decay(df_pre_decay[a], dtype=np.object).astype(df.float)
```