# Is there a built-in method or function to map a function on a numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to apply a function to every element of a `numpy.ndarray`, something like this:

```
import numpy
import math

a = numpy.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
b = map(math.sin, a)
print b
```

but this gives:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I know I can do this:

```
import numpy
import math
a = numpy.arange(10).reshape(2,5)

def recursive_map(function, value):
    if isinstance(value, (list, numpy.ndarray)):
        out = numpy.array(map(lambda x: recursive_map(function, x), value))
    else:
        out = function(value)
    return out
c = recursive_map(math.sin, a)
print c
```

My question is: is there a built-in function or method to do this? It seems elementary, but I haven't been able to find it. I am using `Python 2.7`.

Comment: You might want to look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701429/efficient-evaluation-of-a-function-at-every-cell-of-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.sin` it works element wise on ndarray already.

You can also reshape to a 1D array and the native `map` should just work. Then you can use reshape again to restore the original dimensions.

You can also use [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to write functions that can work like `np.sin`.

Comment: [Relevant link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) about ufuncs in numpy

Comment: Note that the `map` and `np.vectorize` options are much, much slower than using NumPy builtins.

Comment: Now that I know what to look for: for the difference between `np.vectorize` and `np.frompyfunc`: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768245/difference-between-frompyfunc-and-vectorize-in-numpy)