# Datatype of python universal function created with frompyfunc

Tags: python, numpy, types

I have the following question concerning universal functions
in numpy. How can I define a universal function which returns
the same type of numpy array as the numpy build-in functions.
The following sample code:

```
import numpy as np
def mysimplefunc(a):
    return np.sin(a)
mysimpleufunc = np.frompyfunc(mysimplefunc,1,1)
a = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,3)
print(np.sin(a).dtype)
print(mysimpleufunc(a).dtype)
```

results in the output:

```
float64
object
```

Any help is very much appreciated :)

PS.: I am using python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution 
(see also [discussion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768245/difference-between-frompyfunc-and-vectorize-in-numpy)):
use vectorize instead of frompyfunc

```
import numpy as np
def mysimplefunc(a):
    return np.sin(a)
mysimpleufunc = np.vectorize(mysimplefunc)
a = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,3)
print(np.sin(a).dtype)
print(mysimpleufunc(a).dtype)
```

Comment: I knew from other SO discussions that `frompyfunc` returned `object` and was faster, but didn't realize it was used by `vectorize`.  `vectorize` is often misused as a replacement for simple iteration.