# Why `vectorize` is outperformed by `frompyfunc`?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, perfplot

Numpy offers [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html?highlight=vectorize#numpy.vectorize) and [`frompyfunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc) with similar functionalies.

As pointed out in this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768245/5769463), `vectorize` [wraps](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bebc3a658b9c21b12c76b3fcb0a578434ec7267a/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1879) `frompyfunc` and handles the type of the returned array correctly, while `frompyfunc` returns an array of `np.object`.

However, `frompyfunc` outperforms `vectorize` consistently by 10-20% for all sizes, which can also not be explained with different return types.

Consider the following variants:

```py
import numpy as np

def do_double(x):
    return 2.0*x

vectorize = np.vectorize(do_double)

frompyfunc = np.frompyfunc(do_double, 1, 1)

def wrapped_frompyfunc(arr):
    return frompyfunc(arr).astype(np.float64)
```

`wrapped_frompyfunc` just converts the result of `frompyfunc` to the right type - as we can see, the costs of this operation are almost neglegible.

It results in the following timings (blue line is `frompyfunc`):

[image]

I would expect `vectorize` to have more overhead - but this should be seen only for small sizes. On the other hand, converting `np.object` to `np.float64` is also done in `wrapped_frompyfunc` - which is still much faster.

How this performance difference can be explained?

---

Code to produce timing-comparison using perfplot-package (given the functions above):

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.linspace(0, 1, n),
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20,27)],
    kernels=[
        frompyfunc, 
        vectorize, 
        wrapped_frompyfunc,
        ],
    labels=["frompyfunc", "vectorize", "wrapped_frompyfunc"],
    logx=True,
    logy=False,
    xlabel='len(x)',
    equality_check = None,  
    )
```

---

NB: For smaller sizes, the overhead of `vectorize` is much higher, but that is to be expected (it wraps `frompyfunc` after all):

[image]

Comment: Notes
    -----
    The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
    performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.
    If `otypes` is not specified, then a call to the function with the
    first argument will be used to determine the number of outputs.  The
    results of this call will be cached if `cache` is `True` to prevent
    calling the function twice.  However, to implement the cache, the
    original function must be wrapped which will slow down subsequent
    calls, so only do this if your function is expensive.

Comment: From your own statement »*`vectorize` wraps `frompyfunc` **and** …*« it seems pretty obvious to me that `vectorize` is slower. `vectorize` (1) calls `frompyfunc` and additionally (2) does some other stuff. Why did you expect that doing (1)+(2) could be faster than doing just (2)?

Comment: @Socowi because I'm doing (2) in `wrapped_frompyfunc` and it is still much faster than `vectorize`.

Comment: @ead your "wrapped function" isn't at all comparable to what `vectorize` does.  Nor is it comparable to the additional overhead that `vectorize` encurs.  Of course that example is faster than `vectorize`

Comment: I think you need to examine `vectorize` code in detail.  Reasoning and timings aren't enough.

Comment: I have a feeling that `np.vectorize` (and possibly `frompyfunc`) has been reworked in recent versions.  At least some times suggest that.  I used find that `frompyfunc` was 2x faster than a list comprehension, and `vectorize` somewhat slower than the comprehension.  But I haven't found any release notes or pushes to verify that.

Comment: For small cases, `np.vectorize` can be improved by providing `otypes`.  That way it doesn't have to run a test calculation to determine the return `dtype`.

Comment: The `vectorize` class is defined in `https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py`.   `frompyfunc` is setup in `_get_ufunc_and_otypes`, which it returns as `ufunc`.  Which in turn is used by `_vectorize_call`.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the hints - I have used them to dig a little bit deeper. if I understand the code correctly, prior to 1.7 caching was used - this would lead to more overhead for every python-function (about factor 2). Here is the change https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/127ae2f54d2c96fc7318fe12a3e2009e517828d1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the hints of @hpaulj we can profile the `vectorize`-function:

```py
arr=np.linspace(0,1,10**7)
%load_ext line_profiler

%lprun -f np.vectorize._vectorize_call \
       -f np.vectorize._get_ufunc_and_otypes  \
       -f np.vectorize.__call__  \
       vectorize(arr)
```

which shows that 100% of time is  spent in `_vectorize_call`:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 3.53012 s
File: python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py
Function: __call__ at line 2063

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  2063                                               def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  ...                                         
  2091         1    3530112.0 3530112.0    100.0          return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

...

Total time: 3.38001 s
File: python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py
Function: _vectorize_call at line 2154

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  2154                                               def _vectorize_call(self, func, args):
  ...
  2161         1         85.0     85.0      0.0              ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  2162                                           
  2163                                                       # Convert args to object arrays first
  2164         1          1.0      1.0      0.0              inputs = [array(a, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=object)
  2165         1     117686.0 117686.0      3.5                        for a in args]
  2166                                           
  2167         1    3089595.0 3089595.0     91.4              outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
  2168                                           
  2169         1          4.0      4.0      0.0              if ufunc.nout == 1:
  2170         1     172631.0 172631.0      5.1                  res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
  2171                                                       else:
  2172                                                           res = tuple([array(x, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=t)
  2173                                                                        for x, t in zip(outputs, otypes)])
  2174         1          1.0      1.0      0.0          return res
```

It shows the part I have missed in my assumptions: the double-array is converted to object-array entirely in a preprocessing step (which is not a very wise thing to do memory-wise). Other parts are similar for `wrapped_frompyfunc`:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 3.20055 s
File: <ipython-input-113-66680dac59af>
Function: wrapped_frompyfunc at line 16

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    16                                           def wrapped_frompyfunc(arr):
    17         1    3014961.0 3014961.0     94.2      a = frompyfunc(arr)
    18         1     185587.0 185587.0      5.8      b = a.astype(np.float64)
    19         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      return b
```

When we take a look at peak memory consumption (e.g. via `/usr/bin/time python script.py`), we will see, that the `vectorized` version has twice the memory consumption of `frompyfunc`, which uses a more sophisticated strategy: The double-array is handled in blocks of size [`NPY_BUFSIZE`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/dea85807c258ded3f75528cce2a444468de93bc1/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L938) (which is 8192) and thus only 8192 python-floats (24bytes+8byte pointer) are present in memory at the same time (and not the number of elements in array, which might be much higher). The costs of reserving the memory from the OS + more cache misses is probably what leads to higher running times.

My take-aways from it:

- the preprocessing step, which converts all inputs into object-arrays, might be not needed at all, because `frompyfunc` has an even more sophisticated way of handling those conversions.
- neither `vectorize` no `frompyfunc` should be used, when the resulting `ufunc` should be used in "real code". Instead one should either write it in C or use numba/similar.

---

Calling `frompyfunc` on the object-array needs less time than on the double-array:

```
arr=np.linspace(0,1,10**7)
a = arr.astype(np.object)
%timeit frompyfunc(arr)  # 1.08 s ± 65.8 ms
%timeit frompyfunc(a)    # 876 ms ± 5.58 ms
```

However, the line-profiler-timings above have not shown any advantage for using `ufunc` on objects rather than doubles: 3.089595s vs 3014961.0s. My suspision is that it is due to more cache misses in the case when all objects are created  vs. only 8192 created objects (256Kb) are hot in L2 cache.

Answer (score 2):

The question is entirely moot. If speed is the question, then neither vectorize, nor frompyfunc, is the answer. Any speed difference between them pales into insignificance compared to faster ways of doing it.

I found this question wondering why frompyfunc broke my code (it returns objects), whereas vectorize worked (it returned what I told it to do), and found people talking about speed.

Now, in the 2020s, numba/jit is available, which blows any speed advantage of frompyfunc clean out of the water.

I coded a toy application, returning a large array of np.uint8 from another one, and got the following results.

```
pure python                      200 ms
vectorize                         58 ms
frompyfunc + cast back to uint8   53 ms   
np.empty + numba/njit             55 us (4 cores, 100 us single core)
```

So 1000x speedup over numpy, and 4000x over pure python

I can post the code if anyone is bothered. Coding the njit version involved little more than adding the line @njit before the pure python function, so you don't need to be hardcore to do it.

It is less convenient than wrapping your function in vectorize, as you have to write the looping over the numpy array stuff manually, but it does avoid writing an external C function. You do need to write in a numpy/C-like subset of python, and avoid python objects.

Perhaps I'm being hard on numpy here, asking it to vectorise a pure python function. So, what if I benchmark a numpy native array function like min against numba?

Staggeringly, I got a 10x speedup using numba/jit over np.min on a 385x360 array of np.uint8. 230 us for np.min(array) was the baseline. Numba achieved 60 us using a single core, and 22 us with all four cores.

```
# minimum graphical reproducible case of difference between
# frompyfunc and vectorize

# apparently, from stack overflow,
# vectorize returns correct type, but is slow
# frompyfunc always returns an object

# let's see which is faster, casting frompyfunc, or plain vectorize
# and then compare those with plain python, and with njit

# spoiler
# python       200 ms
# vectorise     58 ms
# frompyfunc    53 ms
# njit parallel 55 us


from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time
from numba import njit, prange

THRESH = 128
FNAME = '3218_M.PNG' # monochrome screen grab of a sudoku puzzle
ROW = 200

def th_python(x, out):
    rows, cols = x.shape
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            val = 250
            if x[row, col]<THRESH:
                val = 5
            out[row, col] = val

@njit(parallel=True)
def th_jit(x, out):
    rows, cols = x.shape
    for row in prange(rows):
        for col in prange(cols):
            val = 250
            if x[row, col]<THRESH:
                val = 5
            out[row, col] = val

@njit(parallel=True)
def min_jit(x):
    rows, cols = x.shape
    minval = 255
    for row in prange(rows):
        for col in prange(cols):
            val = x[row, col]
            if val<minval:
                minval = val
    return minval
           

def threshold(x):
    out = 250
    if x<THRESH:
        out = 5
    return np.uint8(out)

th_fpf = np.frompyfunc(threshold,1,1)
th_vec = np.vectorize(threshold, otypes=[np.uint8])

# load an image
image = Image.open(FNAME)
print(f'{image.mode=}')
npim = np.array(image)

# see what we've got
print(f'{type(npim)=}')
print(f'{type(npim[0,0])=}')
# print(npim[ROW,:])
print(f'{npim.shape=}')
print(f'{sys.getsizeof(npim)=}')

# plt.imshow(npim, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
# plt.show()

# threshold it with plain python
start = time.time()
npimpp = np.empty(npim.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
alloc = time.time()
th_python(npim, npimpp)
done = time.time()
print(f'\nallocation took {alloc-start:g} seconds')
print(f'computation took {done-alloc:g} seconds')
print(f'total plain python took {done-start:g} seconds')
print(f'{sys.getsizeof(npimpp)=}')

# use vectorize
start = time.time()
npimv = th_vec(npim)
done = time.time()
print(f'\nvectorize took {done-start:g} seconds')
print(f'{sys.getsizeof(npimv)=}')

# use fpf followed by cast
start = time.time()
npimf = th_fpf(npim)
comp = time.time()
npimfc = np.array(npimf, dtype=np.uint8)
done = time.time()
print(f'\nfunction took {comp-start:g} seconds')
print(f'cast took {done-comp:g} seconds')
print(f'total was {done-start:g} seconds')
print(f'{sys.getsizeof(npimf)=}')

# threshold it with numba jit
for i in range(2):
    print(f'\n go number {i}')
    start = time.time()
    npimjit = np.empty(npim.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    alloc = time.time()
    th_jit(npim, npimjit)
    done = time.time()
    print(f'\nallocation took {alloc-start:g} seconds')
    print(f'computation took {done-alloc:g} seconds')
    print(f'total with jit took {done-start:g} seconds')
    print(f'{sys.getsizeof(npimjit)=}')

# what about if we use a numpy native function?
start = time.time()
npmin = np.min(npim)
done = time.time()
print(f'\ntotal for np.min was {done-start:g} seconds')

for i in range(2):
    print(f'\n go number {i}')
    start = time.time()
    jit_min = min_jit(npim)
    done = time.time()
    print(f'total with min_jit took {done-start:g} seconds')
```